# SwiftUI add image to left side of text field

Tags: uitextfield, swiftui

I'm trying to get an SF Symbol on the left side of a text field in SwiftUI, but the methods used before SwiftUI don't really work. I thought this code would work, but it didn't. Also if anyone could help, how would I change the font and color of the text in the text field?

Here's an image of what I'm trying to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dud0M.png

```
TextField(textFieldDescription, text: 
                .constant(""))
                .padding(.all)
                .background(textFieldBackground)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .leftViewMode = Image(systemName: "lock").always
                .leftViewMode = .always
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's one implementation. Note that there is a bug, where if the initial text of the textfield is empty, the color and font setting will be ignored:

```swift
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "lock")
    TextField("", text: .constant("typed text")).foregroundColor(Color.red).font(Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 16))
}
.padding()
.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(lineWidth: 2).foregroundColor(Color.black))
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! If I were to try say a custom font would that work too?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it would work with a different font. Although the same bug as with color applies. I updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry, one last question, I'm pretty sure this is a bug but if I add hint text to the text field, it doesn't adapt to the style.

Comment: It's probably a bug, since it makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 3):

**SwiftUI, XCode 11.6**

This code worked for me.

**Note:-**
The yellow border outside the view is background view color which will not be there in your case. Outer-most HStack holds another HStack(inner HStack) of items image and TextField. To inner HStack
**Spacer(minLength: 20)** is added move away from the edge of the screen.

```
HStack {
                        Spacer(minLength: 20)
                        HStack (alignment: .center,
                                spacing: 10) {
                                    Image("userName")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                        
                                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 30)
                                        .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 33)
                                    
                                    TextField ("User Name", text: $userName)
                        }  // HSTack
                            .padding([.top,.bottom], 2)
                            .padding(.leading, 5)
                            .background(Color.white, alignment: .center)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                        Spacer(minLength: 20)
                }
```

[image: TextField with Image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can, I might recommend encapsulating your `TextField` and other inputs within SwuiftUI's `Form` container around your `TextField` inputs. This will provide you with some "freebie" styling that can make what you're looking for a bit easier. For example, in iOS and iPadOS, the `Form` wrapper renders each element as an item in a List with the .grouped style. (It's a bit different for macOS.)

Here's what I used to achieve the style you're looking for. One note: SF Symbols aren't all uniform in their width, so you'd want to explicitly set the frame dimensions and padding to get everything lined up perfectly.

```
        Form {
            HStack{
                Image(systemName:"envelope")
                // play with the frame and padding here 
                TextField("Email Address", text: $email)
            }
            HStack{
                Image(systemName:"lock")
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation with ZStack:

```
ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                                TextField("", text: $text)
                                    .font(Font.system(size: 21))
                                Button(action: {
                                    //Some button action
                                }) {
                                    Image("iconName").resizable()
                                }
                                .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
                                .padding(.trailing, 10)
                            }
```